# Принцип работы GitHub и ему подобных

Tags: git, github

Стало интересно, каким образом хранятся проекты на серверах и как происходит с ними работа.
[Тут](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80) описано как настроить свой сервер для хранения git проектов. Может ли быть, что по подобной схеме устроены сервисы на подобии GitHub?

Надеюсь у кого то есть информация или ссылки по этому вопросу.

Comment: Принципы можно подглядеть в исходниках GitLab или Gogs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По ссылке на сайт гита приведено достаточно информации.

Подобные сайты обычно:

- хранят bare версии репозитория (то есть, без рабочего каталога, только содержимое .git каталога. git поддерживает это "из коробки"). Хранят обычно прямо в файловой системе.
- предоставляют интерфейс пользователя, что бы просматривать репозиторий, проводить действия с ним. Для этого используется:

  - либо библиотека [libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/) (у нее есть обвязки к разным языкам)
  - либо консольные команды (у гита даже есть специальный ключ у многих команд `--porcelain`, который делает вывод простым и предсказуемым для парсинга, с версионированем)
  - либо прямой доступ к файлам гита (они просты, так что в большинстве случаев все легко, но возможны подводные камни)
  - или комбинируют указанные способы
- дают различные "фишки":

  - просмотр diff
  - мердж
  - статистика
  - [CI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)
- решают проблему разделения прав

  - управления ключами и пользователями
  - обработка запросов от гита на проверку ключа (на самом деле не гита, а ssh клиента, настроенного специальным образом или http)